# Use RegEx in Google Doc Apps Script to Replace Text

Tags: regex, google-docs

There is a line in a Google Doc that has a time and date stamp. I have written the following code using a regex to replace that line with the current time/date, but I am not sure why this isn't working.

```
function UpdateDate() {

  var document = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var date = new Date();

  var regExp = /[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2} [A-Z]{2} [A-Za-z]* [0-9]{1,2}, [0-9]{4}/;
  document.replaceText(regExp, Utilities.formatDate(date, 'America/Denver', 'h:mm a MMMM dd, yyyy'));

}
```

If I replace the "regExp" in the document.replaceText line with, for example, "3:43 PM January 22, 2019", the code correctly replaces that with the updated date/time, but it is not able to replace the matched regex. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Can you indicate what language you're working in?

Comment: @joanis - I am in google scripts, so I am using javascript.

Comment: Use `var regExp = "[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2} [A-Z]{2} [A-Za-z]* [0-9]{1,2}, [0-9]{4}";`, pass the regex pattern with a string literal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass the regex with the help of a string literal:

```
var regExp = "[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2} [A-Z]{2} [A-Za-z]* [0-9]{1,2}, [0-9]{4}";
```

The [`replaceText`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#replaceText(String,String)) documentation explains it:

> The search pattern is passed as a string, not a JavaScript regular expression object. Because of this you'll need to escape any backslashes in the pattern.
>
> This methods uses Google's [RE2](https://github.com/google/re2) regular expression library, which limits the [supported syntax](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax).

Comment: Awesome. Thank you for answer and supporting documentation!